# Image does not maintain its ratio even with custom width and height

Tags: swift, swiftui

Here i have an image that i want to display inside a stack. This stack has a fixed width & height.

```
Image("greatForestStart")
 .resizable()
 .scaleToFill()
 .frame(width: 450, height: 450)
```

But it does not maintain its original ratio.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pu3eA.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `.scaleToFill()`, try `.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)`.

Answer (score 0):

The image also contains a background, which, in my opinion, is the main cause of the strange aspect ratio. `.scaleToFill()` or `.scaleToFit()` should work fine.

[image]